# How to add HTML Markup to a textbox or label Control in a windows form C#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

Let's say that my textbox control is named messageTB. I would like to know if it is possible to do the following:

```
messageTB.Text = "Hello <b>World</b>"
```

and have the output text to show "Hello **World**". In other words is there a way to enable html markup for the control? I am using visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard windows forms textbox control can't do it.

If you want formatted text you need a richtextbox or some other control.

Answer (score 1):

There's a browser control that you could insert (rather than a textbox or label).  Here's how to set the contents...

```
  string html = "<html><body><strong>HelloWorld!</strong></body></html>";
  Browser.DocumentText = html;
```

Comment: Keep in mind the WebBrowser control is IE itself. So it can be pretty heavyweight.

Answer (score 0):

No.  `messageTB` would have to be a `Literal` control for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's clumsy, but I have used two adjacent Textboxes, one with format set to bold,  to do this.

At least I get the look I want on the page.